HOW GENERATE PRISMA SECRET in Express js using typescript?
I am having difficulty finding the prism secret, I have run the command: yarn prisma:generate but it only generates a folder without a secret key
enter image description here
My expectation is to get the generate key for PRISMA_SECRET = "my_key", because when running the query on graphql I get the error: "Unauthorized"
